# Passing Activities into a Windows Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I'm developing a workflow that will receive hundreds of lines of text (CSV) as input from various files that suppliers send us.  Ideally I'd like to do this using Windows Workflow in order to host either on a server or desktop PC and re-use the same code across several different platforms.

For each type of input file I need to run several 'fixes' in order to massage the data into a standard format for import.  An example of a 'fix' is swapping two columns around within the CSV line, which can be done using a simple RegEx.

What I'd like to do is have standard 'base' workflow that is used by each type of file, but then pass in additional workflow activities as required.  This way if a new supplier starts sending files, we can quickly add whatever rules to 'fix' their sloppy data.

I've tried to achieve this by iterating through the input Activities and using the 'InvokeWorkflow' activity with the relevant input arguments. This works, however it seems incredibly slow - presumably because of the set-up cost of each activity per invocation.

As a workaround, for each Activity passed in I've created a new WorkflowInvoker, then used the 'InvokeMethod' activity to trigger the activity.  This works and the performance issue is resolved.

Is this approach sensible, or is there a better way of achieving this in WF?  Are there any limitations of the approach that I'm using?

Comment: Well, "*to host either on a server or desktop PC and re-use the same code across several different platforms*" isn't exactly the best reason to start using WF. Anyway, you shouldn't be *passing* activities to the workflow, you should **add** activities to the workflow, as needed.

Comment: I'm trying to keep things simple by using a base workflow to inherit from for each type of import.  Does this approach fundamentally not fit with WF?

Comment: There are so many things fundamentally wrong with your approach, I don't even known where to start. WF is very good for long-running processes, usually with human-interaction, where you can easily and visually edit the flow of processes' logic. It might also be a good fit for smaller processes that are recurrently changed and that you want to host as a web service, edit and deploy on-the-fly. With your approach you're not even editing the workflow, you're just using it to execute logic passed from the outside. So, why use workflows when you aren't changing them?

Comment: Where is the *re-usability* on this approach? And how can you host this on *several different platforms*? What if one of your processing activities needs a reference to a third-party DLL? Will you pass said DLL to the workflow host also? If I came up with an activity that posts a facebook status, it means I can pass it to the workflow and it will run? You're just using a workflow to run whatever logic you pass to it, why use workflows and not a thread? A windows service? a WFC service? As you've already find out, they are usually slower than anything else to process data. So many questions :)